# Extracting day,month,year from a given date

Tags: c++

I am trying to extract day,month,year from a given date using sscanf,but it doesn't seem to work.Here's my piece of code...

I have stored date in a char array.

```
void dateinp(char date[])
{
     char d[5];
     char y[5];
     char mm[5];
     sscanf(date,"%s-%s-%s",d,mm,y);
     printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",d,mm,y);
}
```

where am I going wrong?

On input 12-JAN-2015 I am getting::
   12-JAN-2015
   -12-JAN-2015
   N-2015
   5

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is a far superior format.

Comment: but I just want to take input in dd-mm-yyyy format only

Comment: _"where am I going wrong?"_ What did fail actually?

Comment: `C` or `C++`? Your code is `C`, but the tag on this question is `C++`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in `C` while the question is tagged with `C++`. Here is a `C++` version:

```
// accepts 12-JAN-2015
void dateinp(const string& date)
{
    string d = date.substr(0, 2);
    string mm = date.substr(3, 3);
    string y = date.substr(7, 4);

    cout << d << "/" << mm << "/" << y << endl;
}
```

Another version would be:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// accepts 12-JAN-2015, also accepts 2-JAN-2015 (where the day is just a single digit)
void dateinp(const string& date)
{
    stringstream ss(date);
    string d, mm, y;

    getline(ss, d, '-');
    getline(ss, mm, '-');
    getline(ss, y, '-');

    cout << d << "/" << mm << "/" << y << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int day, month, year;
sscanf(buffer, "%2d/%2d/%4d",
    &month,
    &day,
    &year);
```

Comment: you can then convert int values to char!